# Citation with Harvard as an argument throws error

Tags: citing, harvard-style

I'm trying to include the source citation everytime I use an image in my thesis. I have a self-written command to ease that process (code at the end of the post):

```
\bild[citation]{label for refs}{file}{name of the image}{size in cm}
```

When I try to include citation as a \cite-command (using the harvard-package), latex throws following error:

```
<argument> \cite 
                 {ferstl_grundlagen_2008}
\equal #1#2#3->\TE@throw \def \@tempa {#1
                                         }\def \@tempb {#2}\noexpand \ifx \@...

\NROrg@ifthenelse ...eval \the \toks@ \TE@endeval 
                                                  }\endgroup \@gtempa \expan...

\\bild ...-0.3cm\ifthenelse {\equal {#1}{\empty }}
                                                   {\caption [{#4}]{#4}} {\c...
l.12 ...en/aufgabenstruktur}{Aufgabenstruktur}{12}

?
```

The command I used was following:

```
\bild[\cite{ferstl_grundlagen_2008}]{aufgabenstruktur}{FeSi-Aufgaben/aufgabenstruktur}{Aufgabenstruktur}{12}
```

I think this is a problem of the harvard implementation of \cite, as I recently used this piece of code with the bibgerm-package, where it worked like a charm. What am I doing wrong here? Is there any easy way to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance,

Uli

EDIT: Code of the \bild-macro:

```
\newcommand{\bild}[5][\empty]{%
  \begin{figure}[htb]%
    \begin{center}%
      \includegraphics[width=#5cm]{images/#3}%
      \vskip -0.3cm%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{\empty}}
        {\caption[{#4}]{#4}}
            {\caption[{#4} \newline \small{\textit{Quelle: #1}}]{#4}}%
      \vskip -0,2cm%
      \label{#2}%
    \end{center}%
  \end{figure}%
}
```

Used packages & document class:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{german}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ae}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{harvard}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{eurosym}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please edit your question to show (at a minimum) the actual definition of the `\bild` macro as well as the document class and any citation-relevant packages.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I added all of the information as i didn't really know what to leave out. Sorry. I also have to say that I used the same template when citing with bibgerm. I just added the geometry-package.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. And trim down your included packages, please - or add the kitchen sink. And please include the _complete_ error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Answer updated with full MWE)

Not having access to your image files or the bib file that sets up the entry with key `ferstl_grundlagen_2008`, I can't be entirely sure what's going on. Here's a suggested solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{german,harvard,ifthen}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % get rid of 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\bild}[5][\empty]{%
  \begin{figure}[htbp]%
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=#5cm]{images/#3}%
     \caption{#4}
     \label{#2}%
     \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{\empty}}
        {}
        {\small\emph{Quelle: #1}}
  \end{figure}%
}

\begin{document}
\bild[Ferstl (2008)]{fig:1}{FeSi-Aufgaben/aufgabenstruktur}%
   {Aufgabenstruktur}{12}
\bild{fig:2}{FeSi-Aufgaben/aufgabenstruktur}{Neue Aufgabenstruktur}{10}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Incidentally, given that you use the `harvard` citation management package, you should probably be using the command `\citeasnoun` rather than `\cite` in the first, optional argument of `\bild`.

In addition, since it appears that you use the `hyperref` package as well, you may want to load the `natbib` and `har2nat` packages instead of the `harvard` package. The reason for this recommendation is that while `hyperref` works sort of OK with several citation management packages, it really does work best with the `natbib` package. As you can probably tell from its name, the `har2nat` package "translates" harvard-style citation commands (such as `\citeasnoun`) to equivalent natbib-style citation commands. That way, you can keep using the harvard-style citation commands while getting all the benefits of the good interplay between the `natbib` and `hyperref` packages

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. Unfortunately, your solution for the \bild-macro throws the same error with both the \cite- and the \citeasnoun-command. Also, usage of the both packages you suggested throws another error: Undefined control sequence (\harvardcite). There is nothing I would love more than to replace the harvard-package with any other, but my prof demands a certain citation style which forces me to use makebst. The custom bst-file produces \harvarditem-bibliographies, so I think I'm stuck with this.

Comment: @Uli - Sorry, I should have mentioned that you will need to delete all aux files ahead of the first time you run the new setup (without `harvard` being loaded), in order to clear away all `\harvardcite` instances. I've also modified the example code to a full MWE.

Comment: Thank you very much! Works great! EDIT: what I recognized: I copied the source of the \bild-macro from my previous document and forgot to use the ifthen-package. This also most certainly was a problem.