# Cannot compile bibliography with URL in it

Tags: natbib, harvard-style, url

I'm writing my first document in LaTeX and I'm using natbib for the bibliography and dcu as the style.

This is what I've written:

```
@misc{et,
author = "Engineering Toolbox",
year = "2003",
title = "Young's Modulus - Tensile and Yield Strength for common Materials",
URL = "\url{https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/young-modulus-d_417.html}",
note = "[online]"
}
```

This is what I get when I try to compile it.
[image]
I've used the `url` package with `\usepackage{url}` in the .tex file, and putting the URL in `\url{}` in the .bib file. It doesn't work with or without `\url{}` and I don't know what to do.

Also I've put `[online]` in `note` because the actual style I'm trying to replicate requires it but I don't know if it will appear correctly as I haven't seen the file compile yet. The `[online]` is supposed to come after the title.

Comment: You don't need to add an additional `\url{...}` in the `url` field `URL = "https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/young-modulus-d_417.html",` is enough. But you will need to tell `natbib` about using `\url` in a slightly different way: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9445/35864

Comment: I see there that they needed to tell `\harvardurl` to actually use `\url{}` but I don't know how to apply that to this problem because I'm not using `\harvardurl`.

Comment: The `dcu` style I found on CTAN (https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/harvard) uses the command `\harvardurl` to typeset its URL, so if you are using that style you are using `\harvardurl`. Did you try the suggested answer to the linked question? Did it not help?

Comment: I tried it and it worked :) Unfortunately it shortens "Engineering Toolbox" to "Toolbox, E." and the `URL: https://...` is in a weird font. Is there an easy fix for that?

Comment: Write `author = "{Engineering Toolbox}",` (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10808/35864). Personally I think the monotype font is not a bad idea for URLs and don't think it is weird at all, but YMMV. You could try `\urlstyle{same}` to get the normal surrounding font. The linked answer also suggests a way to change the font for the URLs back to italics, which is roughly what you would have gotten without the code.

Comment: Putting `"{Engineering Toolbox}"` did not work. And I think the monotype font for the URL is good, but the part that says `URL:` is in a weird bold Times New Roman looking font which I don't like. Also I thought putting `\emph{}` around the title would make it italic but it isn't doing that.

Comment: Did you run BibTeX and LaTeX again after applying the changes in the `.bib` file? How did adding the curly braces not help? The bold **URL:** is causes by the `\textbf{URL:}` in the redefinition of `\harvardul`. Try something like `\renewcommand{\harvardurl}[1]{URL:~\url{#1}}` or `\renewcommand{\harvardurl}[1]{\url{#1}}`

Comment: First: Since you’re using the `dcu` bibliography style, you really should use the `har2nat` package. Second: After adding an extra pair of curly braces in the `author` field, did you first delete all six files (including the bbl file) and second perform a full recompile cycle (LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more)?

Comment: moewe, I did recompile LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX x2 and it still said "Toolbox, E." and Mico, what are the six files and what is a bbl file? (This is my first LaTeX document) Also what does `har2nat` do?

Comment: never mind, I hadn't saved the .bib file :s 

Thank you very much for the help both of you :)

Comment: Sorry, my iphone software auto-corrected [right!] "aux" to "six". I didn't notice in time. The `har2nat` provides improved compatibility of bibliography styles (such as `dcu`) that are part of the `harvard` citation management package with `natbib`.

Comment: Try changing URL into HOWPUBLISHED. It works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggestions and comments:

- Since you're using the `dcu` bibliography style, which is part of the [harvard](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/harvard/) citation management package, you should load the `har2nat` package to optimize interoperability with the `natbib` package. Doing so is especially important if you plan on using the `hyperref` package as well.
- The `dcu` bib style recognizes a field called `url`. Hence, no need to encase the URL string in a `\url{..}` "wrapper".
- If you don't like the default behavior of `\harvardurl`, just follow @moewe's advice and issue the directive

  ```
  \renewcommand{\harvardurl}[1]{\url{#1}} % per @moewe's suggestion
  ```
- Since the author of the piece is a "corporate" entity, be sure to encase its contents in an extra pair of curly braces. This will prevent BibTeX from parsing the name as having first-name component "Electrical" and surname component "Toolbox".

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{et,
author = "{Engineering Toolbox}",
year   = "2003",
title  = "Young's Modulus -- {Tensile} and Yield Strength for common Materials",
url    = "https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/young-modulus-d_417.html",
xnote  = "[online]"
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{har2nat} % loads 'natbib' automatically
\setcitestyle{aysep={,}}
\bibliographystyle{dcu}
\renewcommand{\harvardurl}[1]{\url{#1}} % per @moewe's suggestion
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} % optional

\begin{document}
\citep{et}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is `har2nat` really necessary for `hyperref`? The [source code](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/har2nat/har2nat.sty) looks like the package would basically only make some `harvard` commands available that would otherwise not be defined by `natbib` and changes the behaviour of `\cite` and `\citeyear` a bit. If one uses only `natbib` commands, then `har2nat` does not seem to offer much.

Comment: @moewe - See [Why do hyperref and harvard not work together properly?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34258/5001) (and especially [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34264/5001)...), and also [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65339/5001). Quoting myself [!]: "[T]he `har2nat` package 'translates' `harvard`-package citation commands (such as `\citeasnoun`) to equivalent `natbib`-package citation commands. That way, you can keep using the `harvard`-package citation commands while getting all the benefits of the good interplay between the `natbib` and `hyperref` packages."

Comment: @moewe - For sure, I would only ever load the `har2nat` package when I'm forced to work with a bibliography style provided by the `harvard` citation management package.